Sympy - return Real solution
I'm using the GeoSolver package to solve 3D constraints.link to GeoSolver - PyPI.
When I solve a parallel constraint I get a complex solution while a Real solution exist.
Is it possible to get only the Real solution?
code:
result = sp.solve(AllEquestions, AllVariables)

where AllEquestions =
['x1- 0', 'y1- 0', 'z1- 0', ((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1, 'x2- 100', 'y2- 25', 'z2- 0', ((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1, 'x3- 10', 'y3- 10', 'z3- 0', ((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1, 'x4- 35', ((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1]

and AllVariables =
[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4]

returns:
[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.000000000000, 25.0000000000000, 0.0, 10.0000000000000, 10.0000000000000, 0.0, 35.0000000000000, -1.03077640640442*I*z4 + 16.25, z4), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.000000000000, 25.0000000000000, 0.0, 10.0000000000000, 10.0000000000000, 0.0, 35.0000000000000, 1.03077640640442*I*z4 + 16.25, z4)]

should return:
[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.000000000000, 25.0000000000000, 0.0, 10.0000000000000, 10.0000000000000, 0.0, 35.0000000000000, 16.2500000000000, 0.0)]

My points are defined like:
self.x = sp.Symbol('x' + str(self.local_var))

where local_var is just a number
when I set the flag real=True on my points
self.x = sp.Symbol('x' + str(self.local_var), real=True)

I get the following error:

File "C:\Users\Achaibou
Karim\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\Macro\fpo\tube\GeoSolver\solver.py",
line 25, in solve
result = sp.solve(AllEquestions, AllVariables)   File "c:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.21\bin\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py",
line 1172, in solve
linear, solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)   File "c:\Program Files\FreeCAD
0.21\bin\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1896, in _solve_system
raise NotImplementedError('no valid subset found') NotImplementedError: no valid subset found


If z4 is 0 then your solution is real. Am I missing something?

This is correct, but I would like this result (only real part) returned from the solver immediately . @jared

Solution extended from answer @smichr where I rewrote the list comprehension with 'for' loops so I can immediately solve the imaginary part, and put in the result through subs to get the final_result and update the dict. Then I check if the dicts are unique before returning the result.
result = sp.solve(AllEquestions, AllVariables, dict=True)
want = set(AllVariables)
unk = []
for s in result: #loop through all solutions
    for key, value in s.items(): #loop through individual values
        if value.is_real is None and value.free_symbols&want: #check if value is img and is free_symbol e.g. value = 1.03077640640442*I*(10.0 - z4) + 16.25
            result_img_part = sp.solve(sp.im(value), want) #solve only the img part e.g. result_img_part = [{z4: I*im(z4) + 10.0, re(z4): 10.0000000000000}]
            for result_real_part in result_img_part[0].values(): #search for the real part in the solution
                if result_real_part.is_real:
                    final_result = value.subs(list(value.free_symbols)[0], result_real_part) #solve the function (value) to get the real value
                    s[key] = final_result # update the dictionary
    unk.append(s) 

#return unique solutions
res = []
for _dict in unk:
    if _dict not in res:
        res.append(_dict)

if result == []:
    raise Exception("No solution found!")
else:
    return res

Final thoughts. Code should be further improved, in the case there are multiple free_symbols to solve the imaginary part.

SymPy is not able to reason out that z4*I is real (though it seems that it should):
>>> from sympy import *
>>> z4 = Symbol('z4', real=True)
>>> (z4*I).is_real
>>>

The value is None. If the assumption of zero=False is used then the product evaluates to None (and then no solution, instead of an imaginary solution that couldn't be determined as such) is returned:
>>> y4 = Symbol('y4', real=True)
>>> 16*y4**2 - 520*y4 + 17*z4**2 + 4225
>>> solve(_)
[]

An automatic way to refine the solution when such indeterminate solutions are given is to explicitly ask for a solution for the imaginary part of such solutions:
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var(
... 'x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4', real=True)
(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4)
>>> want = set(_)
>>> eqs=x1- 0,y1- 0,z1- 0,((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1,x2- 100,y2- 25,z2- 0,((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1,x3- 10,y3- 10,z3- 0,((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1,x4- 35,((-x1 + x2)*(-x3 + x4) + (-y1 + y2)*(-y3 + y4) + (-z1 + z2)*(-z3 + z4))**2/(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2)**1.0*((x3 - x4)**2 + (y3 - y4)**2 + (z3 - z4)**2)**1.0) - 1
>>> sol = solve(eqs, dict=True)
>>> unk = [im(i) for s in sol for i in s.values() if i.is_real is None and i.free_symbols&want]
>>> u = solve(unk, want, dict=True)
>>> new_sol = []
>>> for su in u:
...     for s in sol:
...         su.update(s)
...         new_sol.append(su)


Because z4 can be zero, z4*I is indeterminately real: if z4 is zero, it is; if not then not.

I was aware of this, but it would be nice to only see the real values, but as I understand, this is not possible with Sympy for the moment. When I update my points in the z-value with 10 instead of 0 then the solution Sympy returns is  1.03I(10.0 - z4) + 16.25, z4). So to only have the real part, z4 should be off course be 10 now. Maybe the solutions could be that I look for the imaginary parts and see how to solve them to be zero. Maybe this can easily be done by Sympy.




import sympy as sp
z4 = sp.Symbol("z4") >>>I = sp.Symbol("I")
sp.solve(1.03077640640442I(10.0 - z4), z4)
[10.0000000000000]




If I try to find the imaginary part with the following code: for count, item in enumerate(result): for expression in item:           if not expression.is_real:
I = sp.Symbol("I")
print(sp.solve(expression, list(expression.free_symbols)[0]))                                   I get the following solution:
expression: 1.03077640640442I(10.0 - z4) + 16.25 ;expression free symbol: {z4}
result: [10.0 - 15.7648156273616*I]. What's wrong?

It is solved when I only solve the imaginary part print(sp.solve(expression.args[1], list(expression.free_symbols)[0])). But I think, this is not a very robust code. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

What about multiply by I and then solve re(I*soln)?

I thought this would be the solution but ... , with expression = 1.03077640640442I(10.0 - z4) + 16.25 ; I = sp.Symbol("I") ; z4 = sp.Symbol("z4") => sp.solve(sp.re(I * expression),z4) solves to: [{z4: (-Ire(I)**2/(-re(I)**2 + im(I)**2) - 2.0re(I)im(I)/(-re(I)**2 + im(I)**2) + Iim(I)**2/(-re(I)**2 + im(I)**2))im(z4) - 39645246400170.0re(I)**2/(-3964524640017.0re(I)**2 + 3964524640017.0im(I)**2) - 62500000000000.0re(I)/(-3964524640017.0re(I)**2 + 3964524640017.0im(I)**2) + 39645246400170.0im(I)**2/(-3964524640017.0*re(I)**2 + ...]

when I use this code directly in my program I get the following correct result: [{z4: I*im(z4) + 10.0, re(z4): 10.0000000000000}]

I updated the answer with these ideas.
